# Select a file on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want the user to select a file from an iPhone and upload to an HTTP server.

Example: The *[GoodReader](http://goodreader.net/gr-scr.html)* application has this feature in it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get all the files stored on the phone.

As the comment from Stephen Darlington states, your app is sandboxed and can only get to the files stored inside your app.

You could register your app to be able to open PDF, txt, doc and other files that you are interested in sending to your server and then users would be able to open these documents in your app. Once the files are inside your app you could then use any number of ways to upload them.

Please read the documentation here about registering your app to understand file types:

*[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)*

Answer (score 0):

The file list would just be a `UITableView`, probably with a custom `UITableViewCell`.

There are a number of options for uploading data to a web service. The built-in way would be to use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are some open source frameworks that may be able to help but I have not used them.

Comment: Huh? What files? Presumably you put them there in the first place. iOS is sand-boxed so you can't see files created by other applications.

Comment: I want the list of files like .pdf .txt .doc and other files stored in iphone.

Comment: You can't, at least not if you want to publish in the App Store. Your app runs in a sandbox and does not have access to documents created by other apps. It's not like a Mac or a PC where there's a "Documents" folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found to upload images is to use the ASIHTTPRequest API.  [Here is a link on the documentation on POSTING data to a server.](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)  Download ASIHTTPRequest [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [these are the setup instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions).

How to select a file depends on what kind of file you're trying to select.  If you're trying to upload images you should look into a UIImagePickerController and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.  If not, you'll have to create a NSFileManager to search through your application's files.

Comment: UIImagePickerController and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate is used for selecting images and NSFileManager to search through our application's files.
I want to user to select other files such as pdf and doc files stored in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileManager` Class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Discovering Directory Contents:

– mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:

– contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:

– contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:

– enumeratorAtPath:

– enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:

– subpathsAtPath:

– subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: